# Insert New Objects for Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to insert data into CoreData after a receive a success response from the server.  Everything works great except the insert of the data.  Could someone look at my snippet and let me know if it is wrong or likely something is missing.  The [items objectAtIndex:] return values.  Everything workd except when i do a  `fetchedObjects count` after the below code, it returns the value already in the Database and not the one being inserted.

```
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSArray *item = [operation.responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [ad managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Events"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:@"1" forKey:@"accounts"];
    [object setValue:@"1" forKey:@"active"];
    [object setValue:address forKey:@"address"];
    [object setValue:ayn forKey:@"anonymous"];
    [object setValue:Starttimestamp forKey:@"date"];
    [object setValue:Endtimestamp forKey:@"enddate"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"eslink"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:6] forKey:@"eventID"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:5] forKey:@"eventprofile"];
    [object setValue:@"" forKey:@"imagedata"];
    [object setValue:@"0" forKey:@"images"];
    [object setValue:@"0" forKey:@"isLive"];
    [object setValue:lp forKey:@"lin_priv"];
    [object setValue:Ename forKey:@"name"];
    [object setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Cloud_ID"] forKey:@"owner"];
    [object setValue:pp forKey:@"pic_priv"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"pin"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"profile"];
    [object setValue:[item objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"username"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Success");

    }
});
```

Edit: I added the success block to show.

Comment: Is there an error logged? Are you doing this on the main thread?

Comment: I am actually doing this in the success block of an AFHTTPRequestOperation, there is no error or anything.

Comment: Not sure if that completion block is run on the main thread, maybe try calling your update code on the main thread.

Comment: How you are fetching objects?  `AppDelegate *anAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    
    NSFetchRequest *aFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [aFetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
    NSEntityDescription *anEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:anAppDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [aFetchRequest setEntity:anEntity];
    
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    NSArray *fetchedItems = [anAppDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:aFetchRequest error:&error];`

Comment: It may be issue of type conversation. Check your data type in core data.

Comment: For some reason it is being called 3 seconds late. I set a NSLog and it was being called after the delegate was triggered.

Comment: @Duny may be because, it is in dispatch_async() queue.